# Change timestamp into another gmt+ timestamp

Tags: android

Here goes my code but getting the same timestamp after changing the timezone.

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+11");
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

cal1.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(classListDto.get(i)
    .getClassStartTime()) * THOUSAND);
cal2.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(classListDto.get(i)
    .getClassEndTime()) * THOUSAND);
cal1.setTimeZone(timeZone);
cal2.setTimeZone(timeZone);

long startTimestamp = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
long endTimestamp = cal2.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, instead of setting the timezone in your `Calendar` instance.

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+11");
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(classListDto.get(i).getClassStartTime()) * THOUSAND);

Date tempDate = cal1.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat();

df.setTimeZone(timeZone);
Date gmtDate = df1.parse(df.format(tempDate)); // Put this in a Try/Catch block

long startTimestamp = gmtDate.getTime();
```

Hope this helps! I know its crappy to use 2 `SimpleDateFormat` objects though.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the timezone change in your code if you do a `cal1.getField(Calendar.HOUR);` instead of just reading the milliseconds. Calendar seems to store the millis only in terms of UTC: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()